# Ubuntu 16.04 suspends screen while still active

Tags: 16.04, suspend, screen, login-screen, automatic

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and even when I am working, with mouse and keyboard activity the system suspends and the login screen flashes. I changed the power option but the problem remains.

Here is the power options screen:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but your ***When power is critically low*** option is blank.  On my system it is set to `Power off`